# Redirection Folder permissions on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, folder-redirection

I have a 2012R2 File Server (`server-docs`) and a 2012R2 Citrix XenApp/RDS Server (`server-rds`). Users must be members of `UsersRDS` to log on `server-rds`.

Here are my GPO settings for Documents redirection :

- Basic : Redirect everyone's folder to the same location
- Create a folder for each user under the root path
- Root folder : `\\server-docs\UserDocs`
- Exclusive rights unchecked

I followed this article from MS for setting permissions on root folder : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737633%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

- Owner : Full Control, Subfolders And Files Only
- `UsersRDS` : List Folder/Read Data, Create Folders/Append Data - This Folder Only
- Administrators : Full Control
- System : Full Control, This Folder, Subfolders And Files

When I log on `server-rds` with `TestUser`, the folder redirection occurs and I get a folder `\\server-docs\UserDocs\TestUser\Documents`.

`TestUser` and it's subfolder `Documents` have both the same permissions :

- Owner : Full Control, Subfolders And Files Only
- `UsersRDS` : List Folder/Read Data, Create Folders/Append Data - This Folder Only
- Administrators : Full Control
- System : Full Control, This Folder, Subfolders And Files
- `TestUser` : Full Control, This Folder Only

I have another 2003 File server and a 2003 RDS server, with the same root folder permissions I have only this on user Documents folder :

- Administrators : Full Control
- `TestUser` : Full Control

If I check `Grant the user exclusive Rights on Document folder` in GPO, run `gpupdate /force` on `server-rds`, `server-rds` cannot do the folder redirection at logon and I get the event id 1085 : `Windows failed to apply folder redirection settings.`

How can I disable inheritance for user documents to get the same permissions (like my 2003 servers) ?

Comment: I deployed Folder Redirection with Offline Files by following [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649078.aspx#FolderRedirection_Step3CreateaGPOforFolderRedirection). What you looking for is in step 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the strange ACL seems to be by design, I had to check and change them if needed during user logon with a Powershell script :

```
Function Repair-UserFullControlACL {
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType "Container"})]
    [string]$Folder
)

# We also add System account and local administrators (Replace these french account names if needed)
$OtherAccounts = @("AUTORITE NT\Système", "BUILTIN\Administrateurs", "CREATEUR PROPRIETAIRE")

# `FullControl` for the user
$ACLUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($FullUserName)
$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ACLUser, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

# We need the actual folder ACL
$Acl = Get-ACL $Folder

# Checking if everything already OK...
$RuleOK = $False
ForEach ($ACLRule in $Acl.Access){
    If (-not(Compare-Object ($Rule | Format-List * | Out-String -Stream) ($ACLRule | Format-List * | Out-String -Stream))){
        $RuleOK = $True
        break
    }
}
# Adding fullControl if needed
If (-not($RuleOK)){
    Try{
        $Acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)

        ForEach ($Account in $OtherAccounts){
            $ACLAccount = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Account)
            $Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($ACLAccount, "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
            $Acl.AddAccessRule($Rule)
        }
        # Saving ACL
        Set-ACL $Folder $Acl -ErrorAction Stop
    }catch{
        Write-Warning "Erreur : Impossible d'accorder le droit 'FullControl' à l'utilisateur sur $Folder : $($_.Exception.Message)"  
    }
}}
```

Example :

```
Repair-UserFullControlACL "\\server\shared\userHomeDir"
```